# Convert number to Italian and Italian to number in python

Tags: python

I need Python code to convert numbers to and from Italian.

Looking at previous questions I learned that pynum2word does one way (num -> words) in several languages but alas, not in Italian.

If no such code exist in Python, I wouldn't mind translating such code from Perl/Ruby/Java.

Thanks.

Comment: If you look at the source of the pynum2word module, why not replace all the English strings in num2word_EN.py with their Italian equivalents? It's hacky, but you wouldn't have to delve any further into the source to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Or maybe the spanish module will be closer to italian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do the conversion from italian to number it's pretty simple using regexes:

```
import re


NUMBERS_SEQ = (
    ('dieci', '10'),
    ('undici', '11'),
    ('dodici', '12'),
    ('tredici', '13'),
    ('quattordici', '14'),
    ('quindici', '15'),
    ('sedici', '16'),
    ('diciasette', '17'),
    ('diciotto', '18'),
    ('diciannove', '19'),
    ('venti', '20'),
    ('trenta', '30'),
    ('quaranta', '40'),
    ('cinquanta', '50'),
    ('sessanta', '60'),
    ('settanta', '70'),
    ('ottanta', '80'),
    ('novanta', '90'),
    ('cento', '100'),
    ('mille', '1000'), ('mila', '1000'),
    ('milione', '1000000'), ('milioni', '1000000'),
    ('miliardo', '1000000000'), ('miliardi', '1000000000'),
    ('uno', '1'), ('un', '1'),
    ('due', '2'),
    ('tre', '3'),
    ('quattro', '4'),
    ('cinque', '5'),
    ('sei', '6'),
    ('sette', '7'),
    ('otto', '8'),
    ('nove', '9'),
    )

NUMBERS = dict(NUMBERS_SEQ)

TOKEN_REGEX = re.compile('|'.join('(%s)' % num for num, val in NUMBERS_SEQ))


def normalize_text(num_repr):
    '''Return a normalized version of *num_repr* that can be passed to let2num.'''

    return num_repr.lower().translate(None, ' \t')


def let2num(num_repr):
    '''Yield the numeric representation of *num_repr*.'''

    result = ''

    for token in (tok for tok in TOKEN_REGEX.split(num_repr) if tok):
        try:
            value = NUMBERS[token]
        except KeyError:
            if token not in ('di', 'e'):
                raise ValueError('Invalid number representation: %r' % num_repr)
            continue

        if token == 'miliardi':
            result += '0'*9
        elif token in ('mila','milioni'):
            zeros = '0' * value.count('0')
            piece = result[-3:].lstrip('0')
            result = (result[:-len(piece)-len(zeros)] +
                      piece +
                      zeros)
        elif not result:
            result = value
        else:
            length = len(value)
            non_zero_values = len(value.strip('0'))
            if token in ('cento', 'milione', 'miliardo'):
                if result[-1] != '0':
                    result = (result[:-length] +
                              result[-1] +
                              '0' * value.count('0'))
                    continue
            result = (result[:-length] +
                      value.rstrip('0') +
                      result[len(result) -length + non_zero_values:])
    return add_thousand_separator(result)


def add_thousand_separator(s, sep='.'):
    '''Return the numeric string s with the thousand separator.'''

    rev_s = s[::-1]
    tokens = [rev_s[i:i+3][::-1] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)][::-1]
    return sep.join(tokens)
```

Result:

```
>>> let2num('unmilione')
'1.000.000'
>>> let2num('unmilionemilleduecento')
'1.001.200'
>>> let2num('unmilionemilleduecentotre')
'1.001.203'
>>> let2num('ventiquattro')
'24'
>>> let2num(normalize_text('Dieci milioni e CentoQuarantaTreMila miliardi di miliardi di miliardi Otto cento e quattro'))
'10.143.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.000.804'
>>> let2num('ventiquattromiliardicentotrentatremilionitredicimiladuecentouno')
'24.133.013.201'
```

Note that you must spell the number correctly. In the last example if you put in input the string: `'...centotrentatremilione...'`, with the (*wrong*)singular `milione` instead of `milioni` you get:

```
>>> let2num('ventiquattromiliardicentotrentatremilionetredicimiladuecentouno')
'24.003.013.201'
```

Which is not "correct". But the spelling is actually wrong. I believe it shouldn't be too hard to allow `milione` as exact synonim for `milioni`, or to do add some error checking such that it would raise an error if it finds an incorrect spelling. Just be aware of this.

As a suggestion for debugging the above code(if you want to make changes) is to add a line like:

```
print 'token:', token, 'current result:', result
```

As first instruction of the `for` loop. Then watching what is being done you should be able to recognize the "reasoning" behind the code and see where the bug lays.

I think for the other conversion it'd be easy to implement something based on `pynum2word`. If you don't know italian I may try to help writing it.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! As for numbers to words, it would be best to add the code directly to pynum2word. Thanks again.

Comment: ...almost perfectly. I put in ventiquattro, which I think should be 24 (I do not speak Italian...), but the result was 244.

Comment: @PeriodicMaintenance Okay, it should be solved now. The bug was in `add_thousand_separator`. Now it seems to work correctly.